# C++ difference between two array declarations

Tags: c++

I realize that this is very basic but would someone mind explaining the difference between these two array declarations:

```
#include <array>
array<int, 5> myints;
```

...and:

```
int myints[5];
```

...and why `myints.size()` works with the first declaration but not the second.

Comment: Please get yourself [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 8):

```
int myints[5];
```

**This is an array of five integers.**
It is a basic language structure in both C and C++.
There are no member functions on built-in types.

```
std::array<int, 5> myints;
```

**This is an instance of the standard library *class* `std::array<int, 5>`**
(itself an instance of the standard library *class template* `std::array<T, N>`).
It is a wrapper around the basic array, providing utility member functions (such as `size()`) for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

`array` is a class (standard stl container) that has methods and wraps many functions that you want to apply to more standard static arrays.

Take a look to `std::vector` also. See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
for informations how to use arrays and vectors.

In particular vectors are more suited to dynamic memory allocation, while your `int myints[5]` declaration is called static allocation and has some big limitations in terms of memory that you can allocate.

Comment: Nitpick: `std::array` is a *C++ standard library* container, not an stl container, and not a class. If you look at the [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html), you will see it has no `array` container.

Answer (score 1):

`int myints[5];` gives you an "array of 5 `int`s". This "array" type is a language feature. The object it gives you is basically 5 `int`s next to each other in memory. This array type is not a class type, so it doesn't have member functions.

`std::array<int, N> myints;` gives you an `std::array` object. `std::array` is a class type from the standard library and so may have member functions, such as the member function `size`. The class encapsulates a fixed size array and provides a nice interface.

Answer (score 0):

in first declaration 
    `array myints`;
here myins is a object of array class, which is a thin wrapper over c array. and this class has a function of size() that will return the size.
and the second declaration is a c-style array. this is not a class or structure.

Comment: There is no `array` class.